# Mongodb filter from object data and group from array aggregation framework

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I'm wanna to filter and group in single collection. The problem can i filter data from object and group from array.

this my collection:

```
[
  {
    "a": "gdgdg", "b": "gdgdgd", "c": "sdfsdfsdf", "d": "sgvdgdg", "e": "gddgdrg", "NMUNIT": "CENTER", "PROFIT": "$1000"
  },
  {
     "a": "gdgdg", "b": "gdgdgd", "c": "sdfsdfsdf", "d": "sgvdgdg", "e": "gddgdrg", "NMUNIT": "SUB", "PROFIT": "$333000"
  },
  {
    "a": "gdgdg", "b": "gdgdgd", "c": "sdfsdfsdf", "d": "sgvdgdg", "e": "gddgdrg", "NMUNIT": "ALPHA", "PROFIT": "$55000"
  }
]
```

like this my request body

```
{
    "filter": [{"NMUNIT": "CENTER"}, {"PROFIT": "$1000"}, ...],
    "data": ["a", "b", "c", ...]
}
```

i'm wanna output like this :

```
[
  {"a": "gdgdg", "b": "gdgdgd", "c": "sdfsdfsdf", ...}, ....
]
```

Thanks before

Comment: Can you elaborate on the expected output and the role of `data`? Currently, it looks like a simple `$match` would be enough.

Comment: Yes now is fixed, i'm map the filter and i'm call on `$match` and i'm create object from data like `{ a: '$a', ... }` and call it to  `$group`

Comment: But how exactly you’d like to group them? There’s no grouping result in your example.